# Redirecting Standard Output of a JAR in c#

Tags: java, c#, jar, process

I have a C# app that at some point needs to communicate with a JAR app. No problem, I use the following code to start the app but unfortunately, the window that should print the app's console remains black and the jar file executes in GUI mode.

If I call the same file with the same command from RUN or CMD, it works and the console registers messages from the JAR any ideas why when started from my C# app it won't register any message to the console?

```
[ProcessStartInfo psi32 = default(ProcessStartInfo);
            Process proc1 = new Process();
            string path1 = Application.StartupPath;
            dynamic process3 = pat1 + "java.exe";
            dynamic jar = "-jar ";
            dynamic param1 = "/ssh.jar";
            dynamic args3 = string.Format("{0}{1} {2}", jar, path1, param1);
            psi32 = new ProcessStartInfo(process3, args3);
            psi32.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psi32.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc1.StartInfo = psi32;
            proc1.Start();
            string condeva;
            using (StreamReader reader = proc1.StandardOutput)
            {
                message= reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            if (message.Contains("failed"))
            {
                message.Text = "found it...";
            }
```

Comment: Could you try setting ps132.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow=true;?

Comment: Tried, same thing, actually, the GUI of the JAR still pops